# No module named 'django.core.context_processors' django template

Tags: python, django, templatetags

i tried to make a template tag to get the logged in user `request.user` , i tried this

in the settings.py

```
'context_processors': [
     'django.core.context_processors.request',
     'django.template.context_processors.debug',
     'django.template.context_processors.request',
     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            
     ],
```

and this is my template tag

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def is_member(context):
    request = context['request'].user
    if request.user in request.user.model_name.admins.all:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

i have to make sure if the logged in user is one of members in admins (M2M) field
but i get this error

> No module named 'django.core.context_processors'

and while i try to remove this line `'django.core.context_processors.request'` in the settings.py file i get this error

> 'is_member' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'context'

**Updated - template**

```html
{% load my_tags %}

{% if is_member %}
  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'listings:new_post' %}">
     <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>create new post </a>
{% else %}
   <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login'%}
      <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>Login</a>                
{% endif %}
```

any recommendation i will appreciate
thanks , art

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/#django-core-context-processors) says:

> ```
> django.core.context_processors
> ```

Built-in template context processors have been moved to `django.template.context_processors`

Now your template option should look like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
                        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Also to use `context` in [simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) add `takes_context=True`

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True, format_string)
def is_member(context):
    ....
```

And in your template:

```
{% is_member as user_is_member %}

{% if user_is_member %}
    ...
{% else %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you , but i got a new error "'module' object is not callable"

Comment: @namo, I think you should check your imports.

Comment: yes , but i dont know what i have missed exactly

Comment: @namo, Share your `views.py` and `urls.py`.

Comment: its because i have used 'request' in other views function

Comment: You need to check all the imports you are using in your  files.

Comment: but still i keep getting this error ('is_member' did not receive value(s) for the argument(s): 'context'
)

Comment: Add this one : `@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)`

Comment: i appreciate you really

Comment: @KNSM im sorry , in the template when i load the file name : {% load my_tags %} and then try {% if is_member %} True {% is_member %} {% else %} False {% is_member %} but it returns False True , it should return True True , because the logged in user is in admins field

Comment: It must be `request.user.model_name.admins.all()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227462/discussion-between-nksm-and-namo).