# EmbedVideoField is not being imported

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to implement video embedding functionality. I want to use 'django-embed-video'.

So I download the package like:

```
pip3 install django-embed-video
```

Then I add 'embed_video' to my installed apps in the settings.py file

However, then when I try to import 'EmbedVideoField' from 'embed_video.fields' in my models.py file, it is not being imported. I can't understand why this is the case? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

be sure to add this to `settings.py` to detect HTTP(s)

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

import the `EmbedVideoField()` from `embed_video` package like this.

```
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField #important
    video = EmbedVideoField()  # same like models.URLField()
```

be sure to migrate

Comment: When I add that I get the following error 'No module named 'django.core.context_processors''

Comment: @RandomMadi https://stackoverflow.com/a/65765106/15071244 check this answer

Comment: This is done but the EmbedVideoField is still not being imported correctly

Comment: can you share the error page

Comment: check even installed apps maybe you forgot a comma?

Comment: No the comma is there. I don't get an error just a yellow line under the `from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField`.

Comment: do you use vs code?

Comment: yes I use Vs code, I am on mac. So the commands may differ

Comment: Press Ctrl + P and Type  "Reload Window" and press enter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245553/discussion-between-randommadi-and-enes-islam).

Comment: https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video#readme the documentaition in here is showing "django.core.context_processors'' as updated